# What are the meaning of "put to bare" in the sentence and the meaning of the sentence?

Tags: phrase-meaning, sentence-meaning, phrases

the context is as follows

> ...or complex moment where ethical reasoning skill will be **put to bare** where they will have opportunity to discuss online their reactions to that particular film...

First, what does "put to bare" mean?

Second, why do they need to put to bare ethical reasoning skill

Comment: It looks like a mistake to me.  It was good of you to give us context, but can you give us even more?  It might be a technical term.

Answer (score -1):

It means something will be revealed. `bare` is like exposed, if something can be clearly seen. So instead of `put to bare` you could also say their skill will be revealed. The sentence is describing a complex moment, that will show the ethical reasoning skill of someone.

<sub>(Native German Speaker)</sub>

Comment: That's an interesting interpretation, but "put to bare" is not idiomatic or grammatically correct.

Comment: It is not? Thank you for that comment, I thought I heard it several times in english.